# Is the Visual Inheritance in C# (Framework 4.0) similar to visual inheritance in VFP?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, visual-foxpro

In VFP I can create a class (gridclass1) with a grid, then I create a form where use this class (gridclass1) and can modify their properties in the instance. And Then I can create another class (gridclass2) that inherits gridclass1. In another form I use gridclass2 and can modify their properties and methods.
In C# is possible to do this?
I tried and I can't modify properties of the class in the instance

Comment: Are oyu talking visual foxpro or veterans for peace?  Can't see why you can't modify properties - are they public?

Comment: It is unclear whether you're using winforms or current, relevant technology. Close-voting.

Comment: `C#` is less visual than `VFP`. You have to edit class definition by editing code with bare hands (almost, we have Intellisense). Designer allow you to create form and edit their properties, but class browser is indeed browser. Or what do you mean by *can't modify properties*?

Comment: it's all about [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

Comment: I'm talking about Winforms. I'm using Usercontrols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't particularly work like it does in Visual FoxPro. See [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f26616e-6572-4e54-9ffd-bf91783994c4/subclassing-visual-controls-without-using-the-usercontrol-class?forum=csharplanguage), from someone else coming from the same background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why someone voted to close, but your question is quite relevant.  I think what you want, you CAN, from a FUNCTIONALITY standpoint.  Visually, such as with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), you define the VISUAL components of the datagrid control, of which you can bind elements to DependencyProperties and the visual components can reference these for whatever visual effects.

The app I am working on is in C# using WPF and the split between the "Themes" which is the visual layer to the users vs the C# code behind stuff which apply the prop/event/methods does work similar.  You can define a class in C# based on a datagrid, then derive and add subclass functionality as you see fit...  Ex:

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
   // publicly available to change anywhere...
   public string AnyProperty { get; set; }

   // some property that is publicly readable, yet protected, such as internal
   // control to the class
   public string SomeProperty { get; protected set; }


   public MyDataGrid()
   {
      // have a default hook to some general functionality you want to perform
      MouseDoubleClick += MyDataGridMouseDoubleClick;
   }

   // make protected and virtual so you CAN override this in a subclass
   protected virtual void MyDataGridMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       // anything you want to do commonly for a double-click...
   }

   protected void SomeOtherFeature()
   { // do something based on some settings? 
   }
}

public class MySubclassDataGrid : MyDataGrid
{
   public int SomeNewProperty { get; set; }

   public MySubclassDataGrid()
   {
   }

   protected override void MyDataGridMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
      // anything DIFFERENT for handling in the data grid instance...
   }

}
```

Now, applying the VISUAL components is a different question and answer as themes / resources is a completely different animal.